# IE 9 and JQuery Caching Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a weird issue. I have a web application running MVC 4 and JQuery 2.1.3. There are some users that are getting a 403 response error when the application issues a JQuery call below in IE 9 BUT when we have them clear browser cache the issue goes away. Any clue on what would cause this behavior? Unfortunately company standard is IE 9 but we'll soon be upgrading to 11.

Added notes. The application is using bundling.

```
var jqxhr = $.post(
$("input[name=root]").val() + "Donate/JsonXXXX", {
EmployeeId: $("#EmployeeId").val(),
__RequestVerificationToken: $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val(),
})
.done(function (data) {
if (data.length == 0) {
    // Success.
    $("form#pledgeForm").submit();
}
else {
    HideWorkingPopup();
    $('#myJGrowlMessage').jGrowl(data, { theme: 'error', closer: false, glue: 'after', header: 'Failure', sticky: true });
}
})
.fail(function (e, textStatus, errorThrown) {
HideWorkingPopup();
// Logging the failure reason
if (e != null) {
    try{
        var responseText = $.parseJSON(e.responseText);
    }catch(ex){
        var responseText = '';
    }
    try{
        var jqXHRObj = $.parseJSON(e);
    } catch (ex) {
        var jqXHRObj = '';
    }
    $.post(
            $("input[name=root]").val() + "Donate/JsonFailure", {
                message: "jqXHR.responseText --> " + responseText + "\n jqXHR --> " + jqXHRObj + "\n textStatus --> " + textStatus + "\n errorThrown --> " + errorThrown,
                __RequestVerificationToken: $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val(),
            })
}

$('#myJGrowlMessage').jGrowl("There was an error saving your donation. Please try again later.", { theme: 'error', closer: false, glue: 'after', header: 'Failure', sticky: true });
```

});

Comment: sounds like main page is being cached and token is stale. Could request new token on page load

Comment: note that `$.post` won't cache in any browser

Comment: Hrmm. Let me play around with that idea which is highly possible.

Comment: OK so I tried playing around with changing the token before I make the ajax call and i don't get a 403 from the server but I do get the error I expected a 302 to forward to an error page if the token is invalid. Somehow my users still get the 403 from the server. Any other ideas? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. Apparently our proxy server was throwing the error. Thanks for your help